# Why do I get error sorting credentials in Docker?

Tags: docker-compose, docker-desktop

I just installed docker desktop, and now I want to use PostgreSQL, but when I try to log in docker by using the command `-docker login` I get the error Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out:` no usernames for [https://index.docker.io/v1/``](https://index.docker.io/v1/%60%60)
How can I solve this problem?